# How to assign unique click events to elements in a text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I wanted is:

1. When I click on **what?** text, tool-tip appears with text **"go on"** but I want the tooltip appears on **what?** text instead of **go on** text.
2. When I click on the tooltip, I want it disappears, I mean when I click with text **"hey hey"**, it disappears but when I click on tooltip, it doesn't disappears. How can I set it on "tooltip" class instead of "close" class.

Thanks.
To more understanding I'm adding my work here;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content a").click(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    var tooltip = obj.data("tooltip");
    obj.append('<div class="tooltip">' + tooltip + '</div>');
  });
  $(this).mousemove(function() {
    var x = $(".text").position();
    $(".tooltip").css({
      "top": x.top - 35,
      "left": x.left - 35
    });
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".tooltip").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  font: 14px/22px Arial;
  background: #ddd
}
.content {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px
}
.content a {
  color: #fa6578
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  background: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <span class="close">hey hey </span><a class="text" href="#" data-tooltip="go on">go on</a> bla bla bla <a class="text" href="#" data-tooltip="what?">what?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand .

Comment: `var x = $(".text").position();` returns position of the first element that matches `".text"` selector.

Comment: Sorry again: I too can't understand. Maybe it'd be more clear if you didn't talk about "tooltip", which is usually understood as the `title` attribute of a DOM element.

Comment: Well, just look at your code and step through it. It sounds like you want to put the positioning logic inside the `click` handler, rather than in a separate 'mousemove' handler. You've also created an event handler that hides the tooltip when you click on "hey hey", and that's it, so I'm not sure what else you expect.

Comment: I explained it with more details.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan yes that's absolutely what I want, and somebody just solved this issue. thank you.

Comment: I would suggest updating the title of your question, as it doesn't appear to have anything to do with the existing answers you've said solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to set the position with jquery, you can make relative the `a` parent; also for the `close` action use the same class on the tooltip:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content a").click(function() {
    $(".tooltip").hide();
    var obj = $(this);
    var tooltip = obj.data("tooltip");
    obj.append('<div class="tooltip close">' + tooltip + '</div>');
  });

  $("body").on('click','.close',function() {
    $(".tooltip").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  font: 14px/22px Arial;
  background: #ddd
}
.content {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px
}
.content a {
  color: #fa6578;
  position:relative;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 3;
  background: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <span class="close">hey hey </span><a class="text" href="#" data-tooltip="go on">go on</a> bla bla bla <a class="text" href="#" data-tooltip="what?">what?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @TalhaÖzdemir glad to help U ... to increase opt maybe try to remove instead of hide() because you are appending an element every time you click the anchor

Comment: I have one more issue can u help me? For example someone clicks on the text, the tooltip appears thats okay and we added click event to hide tooltip that is okay also. what if I want to set tooltip disappear in 2 seconds if nobody clicks on it? @DaniP

Comment: Search about `setTimeout()`@TalhaÖzdemir like this https://jsfiddle.net/vd8dd7md/

Comment: yes, perfect! thank you so so much, I am new in coding area and you always make my work easier, thank you and thank you stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0):

You've to adjust the style depanding on the clicked anchor position :

```
$(".tooltip").css({
  "top" : obj.position().top - 35,
  "left" : obj.position().left - 35
});
```

Also you need to use event delegation `on()` in the click event of the `tooltip` since it will be added dynamically to the DOM :

```
$("body").on('click', ".tooltip", function() {
    $(".tooltip").hide();
});
```

**NOTE :** NO need for the `mousemove` event.

Hopet this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".content a").click(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    var tooltip = obj.data("tooltip");
    obj.append('<div class="tooltip">' + tooltip +'</div>');
    
    $(".tooltip").css({
      "top" : obj.position().top - 35,
      "left" : obj.position().left - 35
    }); 
  }); 
  $("body").on('click', ".tooltip", function() {
    $(".tooltip").hide();
  }); 
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto; 
  font: 14px/22px Arial; 
  background: #ddd
}
 
.content {
  width: 500px; 
  margin: 10px auto; 
  background: #fff; border: 5px solid #eee; 
  padding: 10px
}
 
.content a {
  color: #fa6578
}
 
.tooltip {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 3; 
  background: #333; 
  padding: 5px; 
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <span class="close">hey hey </span>
  <a class="text" href="#" data-tooltip="go on">go on</a> bla bla bla <a class="text" href="#" data-tooltip="what?">what?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the position of the tooltip with respect to the element clicked. you can get this easily within $(".content a").click() method.

for second issue you can use event delegation since the tooltip element is getting appended to DOM dynamically.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  
        var x;
  $(".content a").click(function(){
   var obj = $(this);
   var tooltip = obj.data("tooltip");    
            $(".tooltip").remove();
   obj.append('<div class="tooltip">' + tooltip +'</div>');
            x = $(this).position();// here we are gtting the postion of the current clicked element.
   $(".tooltip").css({
    "top" : x.top - 35,
    "left" : x.left - 35
        });
          
  }); 
  
    
  
    $(document).on("click",".tooltip", function() // event delegation
    {
  $(".tooltip").hide();
 }); 
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto; 
  font: 14px/22px Arial; 
  background: #ddd
}
 
.content {
  width: 500px; 
  margin: 10px auto; 
  background: #fff; border: 5px solid #eee; 
  padding: 10px
}
 
.content a {
  color: #fa6578
}
 
.tooltip {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 3; 
  background: #333; 
  padding: 5px; 
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<span class="close">hey hey </span><a class="text" href="#" data-tooltip="go on">go on</a> bla bla bla <a class="text" href="#" data-tooltip="what?">what?</a>
</div>
```